# Teradata Database 3710 Insufficient memory to parse this request, during QueryRewrite phase

Tags: visual-studio-2010, teradata

I am working with visual studio's 2010 and using .Net Data Provider for Teradata 14.0 and receiving the following error.  [Teradata Database] [3710] Insufficient memory to parse this request, during QueryRewrite phase.  I am trying to bring in a simple small table using ADO.net entity model.

Anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Typically this is a situation where the SQL text is "too complex" to be parsed. Can you post the SQL or code that is involved?

Comment: the query is not complex.  I am just bringing in a table from the model view in vs2010.  the sql would equate to "select * from tablename"

Comment: Are you running this against Teradata Express or an actual Teradata Appliance or EDW installation?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a shot in the dark... but if you are in fact getting that error w/ a simple "sel * from table" then it may be possible that the table is heavily skewed.  Check to see what column the primary index is on in the table in Teradata, if the primary index is on a field that is mostly not unique then consider recreating the table and placing the index on a more unique field.  If a primary index was not specified, one is placed on the first column in the table by default.